# Refresh DataPager after an item in ListView is deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

I have a `ListView` table in my asp.net page. Against each row there is delete button. on clicking the button the corresponding item will be deleted.

I have done all these. Also to refresh the data after an item is deleted.

Here is my code:

aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="CategoriesList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table>
    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="CategoriesList" PageSize="3" QueryStringField="page">
      <Fields>
        //fields goes here
      </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td>   //item goes here    </td></tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      BindListView();
    }
}
private void BindListView()
{
  // SQL connection string, command, etc to get the data from database
  DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
  SDAdapter.Fill(DTable);
  CategoriesList.DataSource = DTable;
  CategoriesList.DataBind();
}

protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
  (CategoriesList.FindControl("DataPager") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
  BindListView();
}
```

After deleting the an item, the data is updated by calling `BindListView();` again. It works perfectly.

My problem is When there exists only one item in the last page and it is deleted, The `DataPager` doesn't go to the previous page. Instead it stays in the same page with no data, even no table.

**How to refresh DataPager and go to prev page after the last item in the current page is deleted ?**

Comment: Easiest solution will be to recall the  BindListView() method, after deletion

Comment: Please read question _"After deleting the an item, the data is updated by calling BindListView(); again."_. It updates data. But when the last item is deleted an empty page with no data is shown.

Comment: Can you redirect if you detect your table (DTable) is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

```
use this after your page load event

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // BindListView();
}
```

this will work

Comment: Please elaborate with an explanation.

Comment: This doesn't works. Could you please elaborate with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the deleted event and bind the data source from within the deleted event.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv1" runat="server" OnItemDeleted="lv1_ItemDeleted"></asp:ListView>


protected void lv1_ItemDeleted(object sender, ListViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindListView();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't works. Could you please elaborate with an explanation.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checked if the delete_event method is called during the delete?